# Loss function for Random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am working on a random forest model in R and want to use a different loss function from the default. Does random forest implementation in R allow for arbitrary loss functions?

Answer (score 3):

Its not easy. You will have to build your own tree and then bootstrap those trees.  You will want to refer to this paper on how to build a tree.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/constparty.pdf

Their tree is built with the following code:

```
library(partykit)

findsplit <- function(response, data, weights, alpha = 0.01) {

## extract response values from data
y <- factor(rep(data[[response]], weights))

 ## perform chi-squared test of y vs. x
 mychisqtest <- function(x) {
 x <- factor(x)
 if(length(levels(x)) < 2) return(NA)
 ct <- suppressWarnings(chisq.test(table(y, x), correct = FALSE))
 pchisq(ct$statistic, ct$parameter, log = TRUE, lower.tail = FALSE)
 }
 xselect <- which(names(data) != response)
 logp <- sapply(xselect, function(i) mychisqtest(rep(data[[i]], weights)))

 names(logp) <- names(data)[xselect]

 ## Bonferroni-adjusted p-value small enough?
 if(all(is.na(logp))) return(NULL)
 minp <- exp(min(logp, na.rm = TRUE))
 minp <- 1 - (1 - minp)^sum(!is.na(logp))
 if(minp > alpha) return(NULL)

 ## for selected variable, search for split minimizing p-value
 xselect <- xselect[which.min(logp)]
 x <- rep(data[[xselect]], weights)

 ## set up all possible splits in two kid nodes
 lev <- levels(x[drop = TRUE])
 if(length(lev) == 2) {
 splitpoint <- lev[1]
 } else {
 comb <- do.call("c", lapply(1:(length(lev) - 2),
 function(x) combn(lev, x, simplify = FALSE)))
 xlogp <- sapply(comb, function(q) mychisqtest(x %in% q))
 splitpoint <- comb[[which.min(xlogp)]]
 }

 ## split into two groups (setting groups that do not occur to NA)
 splitindex <- !(levels(data[[xselect]]) %in% splitpoint)
 splitindex[!(levels(data[[xselect]]) %in% lev)] <- NA_integer_
 splitindex <- splitindex - min(splitindex, na.rm = TRUE) + 1L

 ## return split as partysplit object
 return(partysplit(varid = as.integer(xselect),
 index = splitindex,
 info = list(p.value = 1 - (1 - exp(logp))^sum(!is.na(logp)))))
}

 growtree <- function(id = 1L, response, data, weights, minbucket = 30) {

 ## for less than 30 observations stop here
 if (sum(weights) < minbucket) return(partynode(id = id))

 ## find best split
 sp <- findsplit(response, data, weights)
  ## no split found, stop here
 if (is.null(sp)) return(partynode(id = id))


    ## actually split the data
     kidids <- kidids_split(sp, data = data)

     ## set up all daugther nodes
     kids <- vector(mode = "list", length = max(kidids, na.rm = TRUE))
     for (kidid in 1:length(kids)) {
    ## select observations for current node
     w <- weights
     w[kidids != kidid] <- 0
     ## get next node id
     if (kidid > 1) {
     myid <- max(nodeids(kids[[kidid - 1]]))
     } else {
     myid <- id
     }
      ## start recursion on this daugther node
      kids[[kidid]] <- growtree(id = as.integer(myid + 1), response, data, w)
     }

    ## return nodes
return(partynode(id = as.integer(id), split = sp, kids = kids,
info = list(p.value = min(info_split(sp)$p.value, na.rm = TRUE))))
}

 mytree <- function(formula, data, weights = NULL) {

 ## name of the response variable
 response <- all.vars(formula)[1]
 ## data without missing values, response comes last
 data <- data[complete.cases(data), c(all.vars(formula)[-1], response)]
 ## data is factors only
 stopifnot(all(sapply(data, is.factor)))

 if (is.null(weights)) weights <- rep(1L, nrow(data))
 ## weights are case weights, i.e., integers
 stopifnot(length(weights) == nrow(data) &
 max(abs(weights - floor(weights))) < .Machine$double.eps)

 ## grow tree
 nodes <- growtree(id = 1L, response, data, weights)

 ## compute terminal node number for each observation
 fitted <- fitted_node(nodes, data = data)
 ## return rich constparty object
 ret <- party(nodes, data = data,

 fitted = data.frame("(fitted)" = fitted,
 "(response)" = data[[response]],
 "(weights)" = weights,
 check.names = FALSE),
 terms = terms(formula))
 as.constparty(ret)
}

data("Titanic", package = "datasets")
ttnc <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
ttnc <- ttnc[rep(1:nrow(ttnc), ttnc$Freq), 1:4]
names(ttnc)[2] <- "Gender"

myttnc <- mytree(Survived ~ Class + Age + Gender, data = ttnc)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: Please fix the indentation and layout in your posted code.  As it currently stands, it's not inviting anyone to read and understand it.